# How to send a JSON post request with a list in request body in restAssured

Tags: java, rest-assured

I have a json request like this :

```
{
   "clientApp":"PROD",
   "clientTransactionId":"12345443432",
   "messageList":[
      "SUCCESS",
      "FAILURE",
      "BLOCKED"
   ]
}
```

I've tried to create json request like this :

```
String messageList = "\SUCCESS\","\FAILURE\","\BLOCKED\";
requestParams.put("clientApp", "PROD");
requestParams.put("clientTransactionId", "12345443432");
requestParams.put("messageList", "["+ messageList + "]");
```

But it creates the request like this:

```
{
"messageList": "[\"SUCCESS\",\"FAILURE\",\"BLOCKED\"]",
"clientApp": "PROD",
"clientTransactionId": "12345443432"
}
```

If I remove the "" it gives an error defining the string. How can I create this post request, any idea?

Comment: `String messageList = "\SUCCESS\","\FAILURE\","\BLOCKED\";` this statement will not compile

Answer (score 0):

messageList is a JSON array, so you must do something like this

```
String[] messageList = {"SUCCESS","FAILURE","BLOCKED"};
(...)
requestParams.put("messageList", messageList );
```

of course, I am assuming that requestParams is going to be converted into a JSON string somehow (which is not clear based on the code you've provided)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of String, I used array.

```
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
    array.add("SUCCESS");
    array.add("FAILURE");
    array.add("BLOCKED");

requestParams.put("messageList", array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to contribute one more way to do. I assume you are using Map in this case.

```
Map<String, Object> payload = new HashMap<>();
payload.put("clientApp", "PROD");
payload.put("clientTransactionId", "12345443432");
payload.put("messageList", Arrays.asList("SUCCESS", "FAILURE", "BLOCKED"));

given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).log().all()
        .body(payload)
        .post("https://localhost");
```

This is the result:

[image]